# How would I write this query in sql from dax?

Tags: sql-server

trying to write a sql formula to calculate percentage of material number with a division where in a data table there is a Division column with division name, and a  material column with material numbers but some row are null in division column, so how do I calculate the percentage of material numbers with division name out of all the material numbers, some of which do not have a division?
I wrote it in dax as follows:

```
percentage of material = 1-COUNTBLANK('Table'[Division])/COUNTROWS(Table).
```

I tried to write it in sql server like this:

```
SELECT (1 - COUNT(CASE WHEN Division IS NULL THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*)) AS Result
FROM Table_Name;
```

Comment: You need to convert to decimal., the easiest way to do that is to multiply by `1.0`. The more obvious way to write this calcualtion might be `COUNT(Division) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)`